# Can JavaMail be used to connect to Exchange Online Server (Office 365)?

Tags: java, office365, jakarta-mail

Can Java Mail be used to connect to an Exchange Online Server (Office 365)?

Comment: I've never tried it, but per this page it seems to support all the needed protocols: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2021880/configuring-outlook-for-microsoft-online-services-mso

Comment: @ismsankalp89 Edit rejected. We aren't blind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Here is an example I got from [github](https://gist.github.com/brunocesarsilva/12a529f7f752f2853b9f)

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendEmailOffice365 {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();

    private static final String SERVIDOR_SMTP = "smtp.office365.com";
    private static final int PORTA_SERVIDOR_SMTP = 587;
    private static final String CONTA_PADRAO = "mail@mail.com.br";
    private static final String SENHA_CONTA_PADRAO = "password*";

    private final String from = "mail@mail.com.br";
    private final String to = "mail@mail.com";

    private final String subject = "Teste";
    private final String messageContent = "Teste de Mensagem";

    public void sendEmail() {
        final Session session = Session.getInstance(this.getEmailProperties(), new Authenticator() {

            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(CONTA_PADRAO, SENHA_CONTA_PADRAO);
            }

        });

        try {
            final Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(messageContent);
            message.setSentDate(new Date());
            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (final MessagingException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Erro ao enviar mensagem: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

    public Properties getEmailProperties() {
        final Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        config.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        config.put("mail.smtp.host", SERVIDOR_SMTP);
        config.put("mail.smtp.port", PORTA_SERVIDOR_SMTP);
        return config;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new SendEmailOffice365().sendEmail();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Yohannes. I take it that if you can connect to send mail that you can also connect to read the inbox/folder.

Comment: Ideally Yes. it is extremely unlikely to support only the send portion.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has too many products with different names that are really the same inside!  These [JavaMail FAQ instructions](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#outlook) should help, but you'll have to change the host names.